# execute a javascript before submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project where when a user enters 13 characters in the input, then the form gets submitted automatically using JavaScript without pressing a submitted button.

Now i want to add a beep sound when the user enters the 13th character in the input.

```
<input id="text" type="text" maxlength="13" class="form-control" value='' name="order_id" autofocus>
```

```
function play() {
  var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
  audio.play();
}

$("#text").keyup(function(e) {
    var length = this.value.length;
    if (length == 13) {
        play();  //first i need to run this function to play sound then i want to submit form after 1.5 second
         this.form.submit();
     e.preventDefault();

    }
  });
})
```

Comment: The easiest way is to put the submit inside a `setTimeout`.

Comment: You can submit from the `play()` method after playing the audio or use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`.

```
function play() {
    var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
    audio.play();
}

$("#text").keyup(function(e) {
    var length = this.value.length;
    if (length == 13) {
        play();  //first i need to run this function to play sound then i want to submit form after 1.5 second

        setTimeout(function(){ 
            this.form.submit();
            e.preventDefault();
        }, 1500);

    }
});
```

Comment: This will try to submit as many times the user types a char after the 13

Answer (score 0):

Like this. My code will submit after the sound has played - and not before

No need for timeout

Remember to stop the code from executing the play after submitting the first time, or the async function will be triggered more than once

```js
let subbed = false;

function play() {
  subbed = true;
  var audio = new Audio('https://freesound.org/data/previews/254/254819_4597795-lq.mp3');
  audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    console.log("sub");
    $("#form1")[0].submit();
  });
  audio.play();
}
$("#text").keyup(function(e) {
  var length = this.value.length;
  if (length === 13 && !subbed) {
    play();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" action="https://plungjan.name/">

  <input id="text" type="text" maxlength="13" class="form-control" value='' name="order_id" autofocus>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ended` event on the Audio node to trigger the submission instead of hardcoding the length, so it accounts for delays in loading the sound.

```js
function playSound(callback) {
  var audio = new Audio('beep.mp3');
  audio.addEventListener('ended', callback);
  audio.play();
}

document.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.value.length === 13) {
      playSound(() => {
          document.querySelector('form').submit();
      });
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, like I did, However while the form is not yet submitted, the user can continue typing

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in such way:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("text")
const formEl = document.getElementById("form1")
const play = function(){
    let audio = new Audio('beep.mp3')
    audio.play()
}
el.oninput = function() {
    let length = el.value.length
    if (length === 13) {
      play()  //first i need to run this function to play sound then i want to submit form after 1.5 second
      setTimeout(() => formEl.submit(), 1500)
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="form1">
  <input id="text" type="text" maxlength="13" class="form-control" value='' name="order_id" autofocus>
</form>
```

Comment: This will call play and timeout repeatedly if the user keeps typing